# How to add an array object to nested object in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to add an array of objects to an another object whose structure has been shown below.

Here is current response from **Album**:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Skin",
    "artists": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Flume",
      }
    ],
    "tracks": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Take A Chance"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to transform **tracks** object from Album's response to this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Skin",
    "artists": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Flume",
      }
    ],
    "tracks": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Take A Chance"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

**EDIT**: Here is my current models, views and serializers:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    albums = models.ManyToManyField('albums.Album', related_name='artists')
    tracks = models.ManyToManyField('tracks.Track', related_name='artists')


class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)


class Track(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    album = models.ForeignKey('albums.Album', related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

#views.py
class AlbumAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumsSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

#serializers.py
class AlbumsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artists = ArtistsSerializer(many=True)
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'artists',
            'tracks',
        ]

class ArtistsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
        ]

class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artists = ArtistsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'artists',
        ]
```

**UPD**: Added serializers and views!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show your views which create response - DRF serializers / raw responses ?

Comment: @monio pardon my ignorance, couldn't add at the moment, but now updated with serializers and views files!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class AlbumsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artists = ArtistsSerializer(many=True)
    tracks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_tracks(self, obj):
        serializer = TrackSerializer(obj.tracks, many=True)
        return {'items' : serializer.data}

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'artists',
            'tracks',
        ]
```

Comment: I updated  `serializer` variable in `get_tracks` method with `serializer = TrackSerializer(obj.tracks, many=True)` and it worked! I want to accept your answer, but please update it

Comment: answer updated, but using`source='obj.tracks'` should work too